# How to manage many client certs for tomcat mutual/client auth

Tags: tomcat, authentication, ssl

I've instances of tomcat 7 (tomcat-7.0.54-2.el7_1 on CentOS 7 and tomcat-7.0.33-4.el6 on RHEL 6) with clientAuth="true" and vanilla Java keystores.  I've found that I've to bounce tomcat every time a new client cert is added to tomcat's keystore.  This is becoming a problem.  Is there actually a way to keep clientAuth enabled, but not to have to restart tomcat every time?  Maybe by just distributing tomcat's public key to the clients?  I know this isn't exactly mutual authentication, but I may not be able to move forward if tomcat has to be restarted all the time.  I guess a once daily if new certs were added batch process style restart could happen as a fall back.

Comment: If the client certificate keystore is loaded in memory when you start Tomcat, I think you won't have a choice but to restart it when you add a client cert. What do you mean by "distributing tomcat's public key" ? Some kind of HSTS ?

Comment: I was hoping, but not hopeful, that I could set up a trust relationship by installing the server's public key on the client.  This wouldn't provide mutual authentication, I don't think.  Folks will take issue if tomcat has to be restarted every time a client cert is added to the server's keystore.

Comment: Ok, you are using certificate pinning then. While this solution improves the trust **the client has in the server**, it won't enable the server to differentiate between his clients (those who would have done mutual auth) and other clients (those who would not have a client cert). In fact, the public key is **public**, so every one performing the basic Client Hello & Server Hello will be in possession of the public key. No secret then.

Comment: On the other hand, you could create a strong authentication CA. This CA will deliver your client certificates and will be the only one present in the server's truststore. When a new client wishes to authenticate, his brand-new cert will be recognized since it has been emitted by a CA the server trusts.

Comment: This is where I'm a little unclear about things.  In our infrastructure, I've a self-signed CA that I'm using to sign our server and client certs.  With clientAuth=true, I can't connect to tomcat without a having a valid client cert that is also installed in tomcat's keystore (good).  New client certs mean adding client pub key into keystore and bouncing tomcat.  Things are small right now, but we are slowing growing, and will have to support clients' infrastructures that will quickly and greatly exceed ours.  Bouncing tomcat is a sore point at the moment.